# Expired Login token refresh (LifecycleAwareSessionManager)

Tags: spring-vault

We are seeing a situation where after the login token renewal fails because of a Connect Timeout exception (see below for more details), every subsequent call to Vault is returning a 403 possibly because the expired token is being passed to Vault.

I was looking at *LifecycleAwareSessionManager* class and noticed that a new login() is forced only on a null token or when the client *can* connect to the server and receives an appropriate http 4XX exception (in the renewal flow).

But what about the case where the client was not able to connect to the Vault server because of a connect timeout (in the async thread) so the token is not explicitly set to null and the renewal flow is never hit.

I believe since the renewal flow is never hit or a new login is not forced, the vault spring client in our case is hitting Vault with the expired token and getting the 403s.

Shouldn't the login token be reset for all kinds of exceptions to force a new login for subsequent Vault requests?

We are on 1.1.1.RELEASE.

```
"message": "Cannot renew VaultToken",
"logger_name": "org.springframework.vault.authentication.LifecycleAwareSessionManager",
"thread_name": "spring-vault-ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1",
"stack_trace": "org.springframework.vault.VaultException: Cannot refresh token; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for \"https://<server>:<port>/v1/auth/token/renew-self\": Connect to <server>:<port>  failed: connect timed out; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException
connect timed out\n\tat org.springframework.vault.authentication.LifecycleAwareSessionManager.renewToken(LifecycleAwareSessionManager.java:209)\n\tat org.springframework.vault.authentication.LifecycleAwareSessionManager$1.run(LifecycleAwareSessionManager.java:261)
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug in the library and has been fixed in 1.1.2. Please see [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-vault/issues/222) for more details.